# PHP Mailer different mail body

Tags: phpmailer, php-imap

I need your help. I want to send different HTML texts using PHP Mailer. My PHP code works as an autoresponder.

When a person sends a message to my email address no-reply@example.com, the autoresponder should reply with HTML Text 1.

When a person sends a message to my email address info@example.com, the autoresponder should reply with HTML Text 2.

What is the function for my code?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['api_key']) || $_GET['api_key'] !== 'VALUE-OF-API') {
    echo "Access denied!";
    exit;
}


$unwantedEmails = array(
    'no-reply',
    'noreply',
    'no-return',
    'noreturn',
    'automessage',
    'auto-message',
    'notification',
    'support',
    'postmaster',
    'do-not-reply',
    'donotreply',
    'auto-reply',
    'automated-reply',
    'auto-response',
    'out-of-office',
    'vacation-reply',
    'autoresponder',
    'auto-responder',
    'auto-reply',
    'auto-reply-system',
    'auto-message',
    'auto-notification',
    'automated-message',
    'automated-response',
    'automated-email',
    'no-reply-needed',
    'noreply-necessary',
    'no-reply-requested',
    'auto-no-reply',
    'do-not-reply-automated',
    'automated-no-reply',
    'auto-response-only',
    'automated-reply-only',
    'no-reply-auto',
    'auto-message-no-reply',
    'noreply-automatic',
    'no-reply-message',
    'automated-donotreply',
    'auto-no-return',
    'automated-no-return',
    'no-reply-auto-message',
    'noreply-auto-response',
    'auto-response-noreply'
);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpImap\Mailbox;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

// Verbindungsinformationen zum IMAP-Server
$hostname = '{imap.mail.me.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$username = 'example@icloud.com';
$password = 'xxx';


$mailbox = new Mailbox($hostname, $username, $password);


$answeredEmailsFile = 'answered_mails.txt';


$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL', SORTDATE, true);


$answeredEmails = [];
if (file_exists($answeredEmailsFile)) {
    $answeredEmails = unserialize(file_get_contents($answeredEmailsFile));
}


if (!empty($mailsIds)) {
    foreach ($mailsIds as $mailId) {

        if (!is_array($answeredEmails) || !in_array($mailId, $answeredEmails)) {
            $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailId, false); 


            $from = $mail->fromAddress;


            $isUnwantedEmail = false;
            foreach ($unwantedEmails as $unwantedEmail) {
                if (stripos($from, $unwantedEmail) !== false) {
                    $isUnwantedEmail = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$isUnwantedEmail) {

                $subject = $mail->subject;
                $date = $mail->date;
                $email_body = $mail->textPlain;

                echo "From: $from<br>";
                echo "Subject: $subject<br>";
                echo "Date: $date<br>";
                echo "<br>";


                sendAutoresponder($from, $subject, $email_body);


                $answeredEmails[] = $mailId;
            } else {
                echo "No E-Mail sent to $from because rule do not reply to '$from'<br>";
            }
        }
    }


    $fileHandle = fopen($answeredEmailsFile, 'w');
    if ($fileHandle) {
        fwrite($fileHandle, serialize($answeredEmails));
        fclose($fileHandle);
    } else {
        echo "Error: Failed to open the file for writing.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No new mails found.";
}

function sendAutoresponder($recipient, $subject, $body) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.me.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'example@icloud.com'; 
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';


    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'noreply@example.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@example.com', 'noreply@example.com');
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
    $mail->Subject = '### Auto Message ###';
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = '<html><body>Text for no-reply@example.com here!</body></html>';
    
    
    ############ HOW TO SET A CUSTOM TEXT IF E-MAIL RECIEVED TO info@example.com?
    

    $mail->addCustomHeader('Precedence', 'bulk');
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Auto-Submitted', 'auto-generated');
    


    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'E-Mail konnte nicht gesendet werden.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Autoresponded to ' . $recipient . ' sent.';
    }
}
?>
```

I tried:

```
        // Prüfen, ob die E-Mail an die no-reply Adresse gesendet wurde
        if (stripos($mail->toAddress, 'no-reply@example.com') !== false) {
            $email_body = "<html><body>E-Mail empfangen an no-reply@example.com</body></html>";
        } else {
            $email_body = "<html><body>E-Mail empfangen an info@example.com</body></html>";
        }
```

And:

```
        // Prüfen, ob die E-Mail an die no-reply Adresse gesendet wurde
        if (stripos($mail->recipient, 'no-reply@example.com') !== false) {
            $email_body = "<html><body>E-Mail empfangen an no-reply@example.com</body></html>";
        } else {
            $email_body = "<html><body>E-Mail empfangen an example.com</body></html>";
        }
```

But both did not work!

Comment: In your `sendAutoresponder` function, you pass in a message body, but you're not using it. Instead you're setting a fixed message body. Seems like you should be doing `$mail->Body = $body` to solve that. Then it's up to you to put what you want into `$body` when you call the function.

Comment: Thank you. Can you share the full code to the answer because I don‘t know how to do that.